# Capybara: how to retrive the Test Services code value(F603YPW) of an element from below html page

Tags: capybara

I want to retrieve the value of Test Services code

```
<p>
 <span class="floatLeft w30p">Test Services code:</span>    
  <span> <strong>F603YPW</strong> </span>
</p>
```

Comment: I've got this HTML:<p>
<span class="floatLeft w30p">Test Services:</span>
<span>
<strong>F603YPW</strong>
</span>
</p> and I want to retrieve the Test Services code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of the page will really affect what selector(s) you would need to use to get that text, however given only the HTML specified you can use the css adjacent sibling selector to get the element

```
value = find(:css, 'span.floatLeft.w30p + span').text
```

if there are a bunch of other elements with the floatLeft and w30p classes then you could get more complicated using xpath selectors and do something along the lines of

```
value = find(:xpath, XPath.descendant(:span)[XPath.string.n.is('Test Services code:')].next_sibling).text
```

or with multiple finds

```
value = find(:css, 'span', text: 'Test Services code:').find(:xpath, XPath.next_sibling).text
```

Comment: value = find(:css, 'span', text: 'Test Services code:').find(:xpath, XPath.next_sibling).text  ....Excellent, thanks it is fetching the value as expected.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to edit the HTML to

```
<p>
 <span class="floatLeft w30p">Test Services:</span> 
 <span class="your_class"> <strong>F603YPW</strong> </span> 
</p>
```

(so by adding a class to the span),

you will be able to find its value doing

```
value = page.find('.your_class').text
```

If you are not able to edit the HTML, do

```
value = find(:css, 'the css selector').text
```

Comment: thanks for the response, html editing is not possible, so could you please give any another idea, I have tried with ref= page.find(:xpath,"//*[text()='Test services:']")[:tag_name] ref.text but no solution..<p>
<span class="floatLeft w30p">Test Services:</</span>
<span>
<strong>F603YPW</strong>
</span>
</p>

Comment: using google chrome, go to the page, right click and select "inspect". in the elements, right click on the text you want to select "F603YPW" and select copy -> copy selector